# How to automatically get HTML table into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get a HTML table from a website into Google Sheets. I need it to automatically update without me having to manually refresh it.
I've done the same thing with a JSON web page before, but HTML seems much trickier. I've tried [this guide](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html) but I get errors all over the place and I don't understand much of what it is trying to say.

Simply need to get data from a HTML table into Google Sheets using the javascript editor in Gsheets.

I've been stuck on this for a really really long time and have made zero progress from all the googling I've done. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the =ImportHTML command?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en